# Prove that linear operator that has the power of M and equals the unit operator is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have linear operator in the power of M (integer, >1) that equals the unit operator, how exactly can I prove that it is diagonalizable.

Comment: What is M, love?

Comment: M is power of the operator that is integer and >1. Sorry, I messed up the question. I need to prove that the operator is diagonalizable.

Comment: This is false in general. E.g. $\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}$ is not diagonalisable over any formally real field. You need to specify the vector space (its dimension as well as the underlying field).

Comment: @user1551 But it should be equal to the unit matrix. How exactly can I specify the conditions to make it true? The finite-dimensional Euclidean space over the field of real numbers?

Comment: @Valerie It is true on any finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$. It's sometimes true and often false over $\mathbb R$ or a field with finite characteristic.

Comment: @user1551 It is even true on infinite dimensional complex vector spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This property is true over any field that contains $M$ distinct $M$-th roots of unity (which requires that its characteristic does not divide$~M$); in particular it always holds over an algebraically closed field of characteristic$~0$, like$~\Bbb C$. The reason is that $X^M-1$ is an annihilating polynomial of the operator, and by assumption it is split with simple roots (any operator annihilated by a polynomial that is split with simple roots is diagonalisable).

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by “annihilating polynomial”?

Comment: For a $K$-linear operator $\phi$, the polynomial $P\in K[X]$ is an annihilating polynomial when $P[\phi]=0$ (substituting $\phi$ for $X$ into $P$ results in the null operator).